# Magento 2 - add a new class inside column main div

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, php, configurable-product

I want to add a new class inside **column main** div. Right now my layout in frontend is like this:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column main">
        <div="MYDIV">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-additional">
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my layout:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Comment: on your 2nd div where class is "column main".. you want to add one more class here , for example "test" ?

Comment: I want to be where is MYDIV

Comment: I want to be created

Comment: let me explain you again, this <div="MYDIV"> must be inside <div class="column main"> is the magento Blank theme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try it:

> your_theme_root/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns">
            <container name="columns.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="class-example" />
        <move element="main" destination="columns.main" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Replace **class-example** to your css class.

Comment: and sidebar where is?

Comment: and what I post there is the 2columns-left layout

Comment: It is layout inside your theme, it extends standard 2columns-left layout. Sidebars remain on the same places.

Comment: I understand, is perfect thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

Preferred way is to edit in theme's default.xml file. You may create or edit the default.xml file at path **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

If one wants to add container div under column div, should try this.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
           <referenceContainer name="columns">
                <container name="container" label="" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" />
            </referenceContainer>        
           <move element="main" destination="container" before="-"/>
        </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I am getting this error : Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed. after upgrade from m2.3.3 to m 2.3.5 (EE)